# Shell: Echoing a value with colon inside an array returns blank string to calling Java Program

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have written a shell script in bash which will be called from a Java Program.
The motto of the shell script is to return some comma separated values. 
print statement:

```
echo "${arr_SetupVersions[*]}"
```

When I invoke the shell script on the server it returns expected values.
3000:15, 3000:20, 1007:35
But when the script is called through Java program blank is returned.
, ,

Are my values causing the issue? Values are the same as "3000:15, 3000:20, 1007:35".
One more interesting fact is that when I echo these values hard coded, I get them in Java as in shell, no problem.

```
echo "3000:15, 3000:20, 1007:35"
```

(works fine)

My Java code is perfectly fine and tested as it works with hard coded values it should work with array echoed values as well. Hence not attaching any code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely your environment variables in a shell are different than when your java program is executing. Where is arr_SetupVersions being set in the environment?

Comment: Its set just on the line above my echo statement: arr_SetupVersions="["$asVersion""," "$esVersion""," "$bevAlVersion"]";

Comment: This won't work. You use the variable as array, but you define it as a string. You need first to make up your mind: Array or simple value? Also, I don't see any relationship to Java in your posting. You don't pass any data from Java to the script, i.e. the script is self-contained. I suggest that you remove the *Java* tag from your posting.

Comment: How do you assign the values for `arr_SetupVersions`?

Comment: @user1934428, Yes this is not array storage, I have made up my find and storing it as comma separated values myself: Still blanks are passed where variable values should have been passed. What I get in java program is string [,,]

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, I am assingning as in my previous to previoud cooment: arr_SetupVersions="["$asVersion""," "$esVersion""," "$bevAlVersion"]";

Comment: @tarun_tenniso, you might guess the next question. How do you assign values to `$asVersion`, `$esVersion`, and `$bevAIVersion`? Give us a [mcve].

Comment: asVersion="10:50"
esVersion="10:60"
bevAlVersion="15:9"
arr_SetupVersions="["$asVersion""," "$esVersion""," "$bevAlVersion"]"
echo "$arr_SetupVersions"

Comment: In your whole posting, there is no Java code, so this is unrelated to java.  Further, if you deliberately use your variable as a string (not as an array), it doesn't make sense that you access it as array.

Comment: The shell script was failing when called from Java but the error doesnt come up back to java. My variables were not set and as a result were coming blank to java. The reason was very trivial: I was always testing the shell script and calling it from the same path as the shell script was. But when calling from Java this was failing as it was called from home or what location I dont know. But that was the only reason for the failure. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell script was failing when called from Java but the error doesnt come up back to java. My variables were not set and as a result were coming blank to java. The reason was very trivial: I was always testing the shell script and calling it from the same path as the shell script was. But when calling from Java this was failing as it was called from home or what location I dont know. But that was the only reason for the failure. Thanks all for your time.